# Did the Three-Eyed Raven have a long-standing plan relating to Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S08E06 of *Game of Thrones* we learn that

> the Three-Eyed Raven, Bran, becomes King of the Six Kingdoms.

It seems that he at least somewhat expected this to happen based on his line,

> "why do you think I came all this way".

One interpretation is that Bran became what was necessary and tried his best to save Westeros, and follow through in his new position despite not "wanting" anything.

Another interpretation however, is that an old imprisoned wizard in the wilds convinced people to bring a warg (or many) to him and then he took over the warg's body. He later rode south in order to save his own hide and to save Westeros in his best interest, and manipulated events so that he would

> become King of the Six Kingdoms.

He could have likely prevented the destruction of King's Landing in E03 by predicting this would happen, or talking to Jon, or maybe even controlling a dragon, but he did not do these things. He did exactly the right amount to sit on the throne.

Is this all coincidence? Or did the Three-Eyed Raven purposefully plan things out so he would sit on the throne, even if it came at great cost to Westeros?

Answer (score 10):

There is no indication in the show that Bran, the Three Eyed Raven, has a long term plan running to become King of the <s>Seven</s> Six Kingdoms. The only possible evidence are Bran’s wry smiles and facial expressions on becoming king and the line you mention but that is it.

All of the other evidence points to the opposite and that Bran doesn’t want it. In fact he’s said on multiple occasions that he doesn’t want to be king or that he’s *”something different”* now.

Barring further evidence I think we can safely say he did not have a long term plan going to become King.

Comment: I do agree, but it's also hard to say definitely. If someone does something terrible (or fails to prevent something terrible) and then from that they become king, wouldn't they say "I never wanted this?" or feign ignorance? The only counter-evidence we have is Bran's comment that he doesn't want anything.

Comment: Bran's _facial expressions_? :-P

Comment: Another piece of evidence is the conversation that Bran and Tyrion had off screen before The Long Night, which seemed to hint at something...